# Single tag to separate paragraphs in HTML?

Tags: html, css

Are there any acceptable methods to insert vertical space between paragraphs of text without using a tag that needs closed (like `<p>`)?

I'm constantly finding myself in the situation where I've finished typing out text that is too long for one paragraph, into some container: `<div>A bunch of text. Too much for one paragraph.</div>` ..Often there are several other versions of the container, and none of them have paragraph tags in them, so I wouldn't have any CSS set up to style them.

This is what I'd like to be able to do: `<div>A bunch of text.<new p>Too much for one paragraph.</div>`

But this is what I end up doing: `<div><p>A bunch of text.</p><p>Too much for one paragraph.</p></div>` ..Which not only takes more time, but also creates too much space at the top.

At best, I would end up with something like `<div>A bunch of text.<p>Too much for one paragraph.</p></div>` ..which, as a perfectionist, drives me insane. The second part was not the problem - the first part was the problem - it was too long. Why am I marking the second part as a paragraph when the first part becomes one?

Is there another tag that can be used for this purpose? I read somewhere that `<br><br>` should not be used for this purpose, even though it seems like it does exactly what I want. What I'm wanting is a `<p>` that doesn't need closed, but I don't think I'm in any luck.

Comment: `<div>A bunch of text.<p>Too much for one paragraph.</div>` is fine. Valid HTML, both blocks of text are semantically paragraphs according to HTML5, and the `p` element is closed automatically by the `</div>` tag. But `<div><p>A bunch of text.</p><p>Too much for one paragraph.</p></div>` or  `<div><p>A bunch of text.<p>Too much for one paragraph.</div>`plus some CSS to manage the margins is more flexible for styling purposes. And CSS is the tool for dealing with styling issues.

Answer (score 1):

`margin` was the alternative [specified by MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br#accessibility_concerns). It kind of sets a width and height for the element(s) and automatically breaks lines.

```js
document.querySelector("input[type='range']").oninput = event => {
  document.querySelector("p").style.margin = `0 ${event.target.value}px 0 0`;
  document.querySelector('div').innerText = `Margin (right): ${event.target.value}px`;
}
```

```css
p {
  margin: 0px 90px 0px 0;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<input type="range" min="0" max="500">
<div>Margin (right): 90px</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the only solution .

You can use the `<br>` tag. It stands for `Line Break`.

You can also write it like `<br />` because it is a self-closing tag like `<input>` it does not require and closing tag.

```html
<div>A bunch of text. <br> Too much for one paragraph.</div>
```

---

[Documentation (MDN) - <br>: The Line Break element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br)

---

#### There are other ways to make your life easier.

1. You can use [emmet](https://emmet.io/). It is available for almost all editors. (If you are using vs code then it is inbuilt)

**How to use it:**

Just press `p` and press `tab`, it will automatically write `<p>|</p>` and put your cursor in between the tags.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use *br* tag (I don't know why it shouldn't be used. It's a tag element used for that purpose), but in case you don't want to, maybe you can choose *hr* tag (which is a simple horizontal row) and style it with a bit of CSS (just not to show it):

```css
hr{
border:0px;
margin: 50px 0;
}
```

```html
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit vel lectus potenti, aptent primis congue suscipit nunc dis nullam dignissim. Rutrum luctus nunc iaculis enim fames habitant ante gravida hendrerit, praesent lacinia eu tristique himenaeos aliquet duis volutpat, vivamus habitasse dapibus fringilla consequat eget aptent sociis. Laoreet erat imperdiet est duis natoque commodo nisl cum, fames facilisis maecenas vitae odio sapien.
<hr>
Dapibus rutrum per aliquet curabitur urna magna sollicitudin mi, lectus nibh lacus cras tristique neque. Justo lacinia gravida aliquam phasellus natoque parturient vulputate, praesent turpis cum ad felis posuere suspendisse laoreet, ornare bibendum dignissim ultrices condimentum molestie. Platea taciti aliquet conubia etiam natoque hac neque justo diam magnis sollicitudin viverra per faucibus, mollis interdum rutrum penatibus et ullamcorper suscipit bibendum malesuada senectus facilisi ad.
```

Comment: It isn't ideal for people that require screen readers: [read more on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br#accessibility_concerns)

Comment: That's pretty clever. It almost matches its original purpose. Not too bad!

Comment: `<br>` is formally for a *semantic* line break, not a styling line break. Semantic line breaks occur between lines of addresses, and between the lines of verses of poems and music lyrics. `<hr>` is for a thematic break. There's no suggestion of a thematic break in the content as described in the question.